# Memory exhaustion while running NDSolve

Tags: windows, memory, wolfram-mathematica

I run into the "No more memory available" error message in Mathematica. I understand that "Parallelize[]" isn't (obviously) going to help me. Neither has "ClearSystemCache[]".

What gives? Do I just need more RAM?

### My Code

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
Clear[Eq4, EvapThickFilm, h, S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]
Eq4[h_, {S_, G_, E1_, K1_, D1_, VR_, M_, R_}] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]h\) + 
    Div[-h^3 G Grad[h] + 
      h^3 S Grad[Laplacian[h]] + (VR E1^2 h^3)/(D1 (h + K1)^3)
        Grad[h] + M (h/(1 + h))^2 Grad[h]] + E1/(
    h + K1) + (R/6) D[D[(h^2/(1 + h)), x] h^3, x] == 0;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];
EvapThickFilm[S_, G_, E1_, K1_, D1_, VR_, M_, R_] := 
  Eq4[h[x, y, t], {S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R}];
TraditionalForm[EvapThickFilm[S, G, E1, K1, D1, VR, M, R]];

L = 318; TMax = 10;
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear[Kvar];
Kvar[t_] :=  Piecewise[{{1, t <= 1}, {2, t > 1}}]
(*Ktemp = Array[0.001+0.001#^2&,13]*)
hSol = h /. NDSolve[{
     (*S,G,E,K,D,VR,M*)

     EvapThickFilm[1, 3, 0.1, 7, 0.01, 0.1, 0, 160],
     h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t],
     h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t],
     (*h[x,y,0] == 1.1+Cos[x] Sin[2y] *)
     h[x, y, 0] == 
      1 + (-0.25 Cos[2 \[Pi] x/L] - 0.25 Sin[2 \[Pi] x/L]) Cos[
         2 \[Pi] y/L]
     },
    h,
    {x, 0, L},
    {y, 0, L},
    {t, 0, TMax},
    MaxStepSize -> 0.1
    ][[1]]

hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[hSol];
```

### Error message

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

### My OS specs

Intel Core 2 Duo with 4.00 GB ram, 64 bit OS (Windows 7)

Comment: Not that it matters here probably, but if you ever get this message the first thing to do is

First, set $HistoryLength=0. A number of these error messages for larger programs are caused by this.

Second, Isolate the actual line of code which causes the memory problem. If possible run it in a way that you can monitor the memory usage.

Comment: @Searke
That is a very useful suggestion. If I may ask, how should I _isolate_ the portion of code that is causing the problem? I am new to Mathematica and I don't know of functions off the top of my head.

Comment: @DNA See related [answer on memory usage control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773009/subkernel-memory-control-in-mathematica/6805237#6805237).

Comment: Related question: "[Profiling memory usage in Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418892/profiling-memory-usage-in-mathematica)".

Comment: You've posted this pde 3 times, and it is the nastiest differential equation I've encountered. Have you tried any simplifications? For instance, using the coefficients you've supplied you end up with `Div[h^3 Grad[G h + S Laplacian[h]]]` plus 4 other terms. Two of those terms are multiplied by 0.1, so somewhat small and ignorable at a first look. I'd try to solve it that way first, possibly taking advantage of the periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, you are absolutely right. It is rather nasty. It models an evaporating liquid film with several physical mechanisms being modeled by each of the terms in the PDE. I have solved simplified versions of this equation in MATLAB and in MATHEMATICA using periodic BCs. I am now trying to solve the entire equation itself with ALL TERMS INVOLVED (hence all physical mechanisms that govern film evaporation included). I have been borderline successful. However,(going off on a tangent), I'd need to do a linear stability analysis to determine the domain in which I should solve this pde.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you. I will read the page.

Comment: Also, do you intend an asymmetric treatment of the x and y directions? I'm specifically referring to the last derivative term which is only in x, not y.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I am not yet sure if or not I'll attempt an axisymmetric treatment of the problem.

Comment: @Searke `$HistoryLength=0` didn't solve the problem. I guess it has to be something else.

Comment: I tried reducing x, y and t intervals, manipulating MaxStepSize but nothing helps. I have 8 GB of memory but I can see memory consumption grow out of bound with the same characteristic profile no matter the interval choices. Perhaps the function is oscillating heavily or has fractal characteristics.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries See answer below :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you may get a taste of what is happening:

Replace

```
MaxStepSize -> 0.1
```

by

```
MaxStepFraction -> 1/30
```

And run your code.

Then:

```
p = Join[#,Reverse@#]&@ 
     Table[Plot3D[hSol[x, y, i], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
                  PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 4}}], 
     {i, 7, 8, .1}]

Export["c:\\plot.gif", p]
```

So, Mma is trying to refine the solution at those peaks, to no avail.
[image]